# Not understanding how a list works in a recursive function in C

Tags: c, list

I have trouble understanding what happens to a list when I use a function to insert some values in it. The exercise is to duplicate all the even element of a list. As you can see I wrote some comments (in the function) to better understand what's the problem of my code.
The function works without return and I can't understand why. To make it work I have to use it like a void function on the second call.
The integral code can be found at
https://replit.com/@Vash221/evenDub?v=1

Here you can see just the main function.

```
/*
Complete the listDupEven function which, given a list, duplicates all even numbers;
The function must use recursion
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include "TList.h"
//RECURSIVE FUNCTION
TList listDupEven(TList list)
{
  if(list==NULL)
    return list;
  if(list->info%2==0)    
    {
      list=listInsert(list, list->info);
      list=list->link;
    }
  //If I delete the return and use the function like a void it works:
  //listDupEven(list->link);
  return listDupEven(list->link);
  //If I put a return it doesn't work
}
int main(void) {

  TList list=listCreate();
  list=listInsert(list, 1);
  listInsert(list, 2);
  listInsert(list, 3);
  listInsert(list, 4);
  listInsert(list, 5);
  listInsert(list, 6);

  list=listDupEven(list);
  printf("The new list is:\n");
  listPrint(list);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Put all the relevant code in the question (not in a link). Remove everything not related to the question.

Comment: In the absence of an explicit return value, the implicit return value is undefined. It *might* actually turn out to be the original `list` pointer itself which may be why the code appears to work (depending on what you mean by "it works").

Comment: _Side note:_ Linked list deletion is a _poor_ use of recursion. It doesn't scale well (e.g.) If you had 10,000,000 elements in the list, you'd probably overflow the stack. And, it's slower than an iterative solution.

Comment: @CraigEstey is a tail recursive function, any decent compiler is protected from stack overflow in this case.

Comment: I don't need to optmize the code

Comment: For one thing you cannot change what list is pointing through via the parameter i.e. `list` but you still do `list=listInsert(list, list->info); list=list->link;` in the function as if you could. In order to change list you need to pass the address of list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the culprit here is this  :

```
if(list==NULL)
    return list;
```

You are returning a NULL pointer .
You can fix this in many ways , for example you can do this :

```
TList listDupEven(TList list , TList orig)
{                             
  if(list==NULL)              
    return orig;
  if(list->info%2==0)     
    {
      list=listInsert(list, list->info);
      list=list->link;
    }

  return listDupEven(list->link , orig);
 
}
```

`orig` is just the original pointer you pass to your function :
`list = listDupEven(list , list) ;`

The reason it did work when removing the return statement (and by that , I imagine you are talking about a void function , rather than a function without return statement , which is undefined behavior by the way) , is because you didn't overwrite your `list` pointer by NULL .

Edit :
This can work also :

```
TList listDupEven(TList list)
{
  if(list==NULL)
    return NULL;                                                                                               
  if(list->info%2==0)    
    {
      list=listInsert(list, list->info);
      list=list->link;
    }
  listDupEven(list->link); 
  return list;                                                                                                                       
}
```

Comment: I can't modify the prototype of the function though. Is there another solution? (It's a college exercise)

Comment: @RaffaeleLungarella hmm , check the new function in the answer

Comment: Thanks i actually put the return of the function in a useless variable because i don't feel very confortable to use the function like a void. But the code is the same